# How to get a smooth continuous pdf of a Bayesian Gaussian mixture model?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Given the code below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture

df = pd.read_csv("dataset", delimiter=" ")
data = df.to_numpy()
X_train = np.reshape(data, (10*data.shape[0],2))

bgmm = BayesianGaussianMixture(n_components=15,
                               random_state=7,
                               max_iter=5000,
                               n_init=10,
                               weight_concentration_prior_type="dirichlet_distribution")

bgmm.fit(X_train)
logprob = bgmm.score_samples(X_train)
pdf = np.exp(logprob)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, num=20)
plt.plot(x, pdf, '-k', label='Mixture PDF')
plt.show()
```

I get the following discrete pdf:

[image]

How can I plot a smooth continuous version of this pdf?

**Edit**:

```
Here is the the dataset:

[[6.11507621 6.2285484 ]
 [5.61154419 7.4166868 ]
 [5.3638034  8.64581576]
 [8.58030274 6.01384676]
 [2.06883754 8.5662325 ]
 [7.772149   2.29177372]
 [0.66223423 0.01642353]
 [7.42461573 5.46288677]
 [0.82355307 3.60322705]
 [1.12966405 9.54888118]
 [4.34716189 3.63203485]
 [7.95368286 5.74659859]
 [3.21564946 3.67576324]
 [6.48021187 7.35190659]
 [3.02668358 4.41981514]
 [0.01745485 7.49153586]
 [1.08490595 0.91004064]
 [1.89995405 0.38728879]
 [4.40549506 2.48715052]
 [4.52857064 1.24935027]]
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but try `num=200` or something like that in the arguments for `linspace`.

Comment: @RobertDodier: The `pdf` variable includes only 20 entries. So, choosing anything except `num=20` yields to mismatch while plotting.

Comment: Well, a Gaussian mixture is a continuous function, so you can add smoothness to the plot by evaluating it at many points, even if those parts are not in the data set. Anyway it wouldn't hurt if you would post the data set you're working with.

Comment: @RobertDodier: I just added the dataset, if you check the edit.

Comment: I don't think what's being plotted is the pdf of the GM; either you want to plot something else (not the pdf), or you want to plot the pdf, and you need to change the plotting stuff. I'll assume you actually do want the pdf, in which case what you need to do is construct a two-dimensional grid with more or less the same range as the data sample, and evaluate the GM pdf on that grid. You might want to only use a few bumps (let's say 2 or 3) if you have only 20 data points.

Comment: I don't understand your data input is a `Nx2` array and the you evaluate with some vector to try to see pdf?

Comment: Right. I should have tried to create a bivariate pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data are x and y values in 2D, you could try the following code to start experimenting:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture

data = np.array([[6.11507621, 6.2285484], [5.61154419, 7.4166868], [5.3638034, 8.64581576], [8.58030274, 6.01384676],
                 [2.06883754, 8.5662325], [7.772149, 2.29177372], [0.66223423, 0.01642353], [7.42461573, 5.46288677],
                 [0.82355307, 3.60322705], [1.12966405, 9.54888118], [4.34716189, 3.63203485], [7.95368286, 5.74659859],
                 [3.21564946, 3.67576324], [6.48021187, 7.35190659], [3.02668358, 4.41981514], [0.01745485, 7.49153586],
                 [1.08490595, 0.91004064], [1.89995405, 0.38728879], [4.40549506, 2.48715052], [4.52857064, 1.24935027]])


X_train = data

bgmm = BayesianGaussianMixture(n_components=15,
                               random_state=7,
                               max_iter=5000,
                               n_init=10,
                               weight_concentration_prior_type="dirichlet_distribution")

bgmm.fit(X_train)
# create a mesh of points with x and y values going from -1 to 11
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 11, 30), np.linspace(-1, 11, 30))
# recombine x and y to tuples
xy = np.array([x.ravel(), y.ravel()]).T
logprob = bgmm.score_samples(xy)
pdf = np.exp(logprob).reshape(x.shape)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 6))

# show the result of bgmm.score_samples on a mesh
ax1.imshow(pdf, extent=[-1, 11, -1, 11], cmap='Blues', interpolation='bilinear', origin='lower')
# show original data in red
ax1.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], color='red')
ax1.set_title('BayesianGaussianMixture')

# create a seaborn kdeplot from the same data
sns.kdeplot(x=data[:, 0], y=data[:, 1], fill=True, ax=ax2)
ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], color='red')
ax2.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
ax2.set_xlim(-1, 11)
ax2.set_ylim(-1, 11)
ax2.set_title('Seaborn kdeplot')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: BayesianGaussianMixture vs sns.kdeplot]

Comment: Thanks, However when I run the code, it throws: `sns.kdeplot(x=data[:, 0], y=data[:, 1], fill=True, ax=ax2)
TypeError: kdeplot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

Comment: I tried this with the latest seaborn version 0.11.2